# XML validation, nested XSD and UNC paths

Tags: php, xml, xsd

I want to validate an XML document against a local XSD file using XMLReader on PHP/5.3.0. The schema is called `test.xsd` and it contains a reference to a second schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="common.xsd"/>
```

I have a copy of all files in the same directory. The relevant part of the code looks like this:

```
<?php

define('DIR_XML', dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'samples' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

$oXMLReader = new XMLReader;

$oXMLReader->open('test.xml');
$oXMLReader->setSchema(DIR_XML . 'test.xsd');

while( $oXMLReader->read() ){
}
$oXMLReader->close();

?>
```

My code **works fine** if the `samples` directory is local to the web server and reachable by a **drive letter**, e.g.:

```
define('DIR_XML', 'C:\samples' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

However, real data is in a network drive reachable by UNC path:

```
\\SERVER\WEB PROJECTS\foo\samples
```

And here's the problem: in such case (and only in such case) PHP loads `test.xsd` just fine but it cannot find `common.xsd`. I get a warning:

> Warning: XMLReader::setSchema()
>   [xmlreader.setschema]: Unable to set
>   schema. This must be set prior to
>   reading or schema contains errors.

... and the following XML errors:

> Warning 1549 (Start element): failed
>   to load external entity
>   "/SERVER/WEB%20PROJECTS/foo/samples/common.xsd"
>
> Error 3050 (Start element): Element
>   '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}include':
>   Failed to load the document
>   '/SERVER/WEB%20PROJECTS/foo/samples/common.xsd'
>   for inclusion.

It seems that PHP is misinterpreting the UNC path as a URL :-?

Is there any option or trick to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i ran into a similar issue and the only way i could fix it was using a symlink from local HDD to UNC path (windows): `mklink /D "C:\SomeDir" "//Some//UNC//Path"`

would have thought that this would also work on linux

Comment: I eventually got tired and just symlinked all my important network paths. There're just too many applications that won't support UNC.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without seeing what the string storing `\\SERVER\WEB PROJECTS\foo\sample` looks like. This might be a cause of escaping needed, as `\\` produces `\`, and `\\\\` is needed to produce `\\`.

Comment: Well, PHP is able to use that same path to find `test.xml` and `test.xsd`, but not `common.xsd` which is on the same directory. How can I affect the way libxml handles path internally?